# How to make python script wait until entering specific URL

Tags: python, selenium, url, selenium-webdriver, random

I want python script to be triggered by entering specific URLs with specific part of address.

Here is an example:

```
http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1234
#1234 can be any random 4 digits Number
```

Basically I want python script to activate when URL has "http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=" in it.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 9999)
desired_url = http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=\d{4}
def wait_for_correct_current_url):
      wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == desired_url)



driver.get("http://www.google.com")
wait_for_correct_current_url(desired_url)
**(Script that activates after entering desired_url)**
```

I am wondering if regex will do the trick, but I am new to python... so what do i know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this selenium api [expected_conditions.url_changes](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=url_contains#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_contains)

Comment: I got this: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'support'

Answer (score 1):

Use like this,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.url_contains("desired_url"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information about your *usecase* would have helped to provide a more canonical answer.

However to invoke a URL with specific part of address to be random, you can identify the range through `range()` and iterate the range through `format()` to construct the complete *URL* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  for i in range(1000,1010):
      desired_url = "http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER={}".format(i)
      print(desired_url)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1000
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1001
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1002
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1003
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1004
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1005
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1006
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1007
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1008
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1009
  ```

Incase you are looking for random numbers as a part of the *URL*, you can use `randrange()` to generate as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import random

  for i in range(0,10) :
      desired_url = "http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER={}".format(str(random.randrange(1000, 9999)))
      print(desired_url)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=8776
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1662
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=3255
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=1524
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=6463
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=4511
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=3273
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=7471
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=4672
  http://11.111.11.11:0000/Menu_EXAMPLE.jsp?NUMBER=2828
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all answers above with no luck. Thanks anyways.
I guess my explanation was quite not enough

This did a trick for me.

```
def condition(driver):
look_for = ("Any word within expected URL1", "Any word within expected URL2")
url = driver.current_url
for s in look_for:
    if url.find(s) != -1:
        [Any Script I want to activate]

return False

wait.until(condition)
```

Comment: How does this solution answers the question where you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54799859/1) _...script to be triggered by entering specific URLs with specific part of address..._ and you were looking for _...I am wondering if regex will do the trick, but I am new to python... so what do i know..._?